# C# code does not detect webcam always

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, codeplex

I use fallowing library to detect webcam for simple c# application. When it debug works fine and when I try again It give fallowing error.

[Used reference](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/)
If somebody has any idea about it please help me to solve it.

[First get this box](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2vttkc7.jpg) and when click OK get fallowing error message.

> an error occurred while capturing the video image. the video capture
>   will now be terminated. Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WinFormCharpWebCam;

namespace camTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        WebCam webcam;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.Stop();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.Continue();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam = new WebCam();
            webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
        }
    }
}
```

**Webcam.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WebCam_Capture;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
{
    //Design by Pongsakorn Poosankam
    class WebCam
    {
        private WebCamCapture webcam;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
        private int FrameNumber = 30;
        public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
        {
            webcam = new WebCamCapture();
            webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
            webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
            webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
            _FrameImage = ImageControl;
        }

        void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
        {
            _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
            webcam.Start(0);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            webcam.Stop();
        }

        public void Continue()
        {
            // change the capture time frame
            webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;

            // resume the video capture from the stop
            webcam.Start(this.webcam.FrameNumber);
        }

        public void ResolutionSetting()
        {
            webcam.Config();
        }

        public void AdvanceSetting()
        {
            webcam.Config2();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed you have not initialised _FrameImage which would indeed be expected to throw this error.

_FrameImage = new PictureBox();
_FrameImage = ImageControl;

Comment: @JuStDaN he is initializing the FrameImage with _FrameImage = ImageControl; no need to do it twice.